# Remove chapter number space arising from \chapter*{}

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

I am using the `titlesec` package to format my chapters in the following way:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}{\rmfamily\bfseries}{\resizebox{!}{2cm}{\Roman{chapter}}}{0pt}{\vskip 0.25\baselineskip \raggedright\sffamily\Huge}
```

This produces the chapter number in roman numerals, then the chapter name underneath it. It works well when I use the `\chapter` command.

But when I use `\chapter*{}`, I get a 2cm blank space and then the title of the chapter underneath that space. For `\chapter*{}`, I want the chapter name to start at the same position as the chapter number does for `\chapter{}`. How can I do this?

Comment: use `numberless` variant

Comment: @touhami: Answering or closing?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer i can't find a duplicate. If   you have an answer please post it.

Comment: @touhami: Well, you suggested `numberless` -- isn't that the answer? I don't use `titlesec`, I can't answer this!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer your wish is my command ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The titlesec package provides `numberless` option for `\titleformat`  to be used in case of no label (starred sections)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\rmfamily\bfseries}{\resizebox{!}{2cm}{\Roman{chapter}}}{0pt}{\vskip 0.25\baselineskip \raggedright\sffamily\Huge}
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}{\rmfamily\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\raggedright\sffamily\Huge}
\begin{document}
\chapter{foo}
\chapter*{foo}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A quick answer (+1)